# Recursion tree of 2T(n/4) + T(n/3) + n

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I have been trying to solve this recurrence solution with recursion tree.
I knew that the first level contributes n. Second contributes 5/6 n. Supposedly, third level should contribute 25/36 n but for the love of god, I don't know how to get 25/36 n in the third level. As I thought the third level recurrence will (n/16+n/16+n/9)*3.

Can anyone provide any insight or teach me how to reach 25/36 n in the third level?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain how you arrived at 5/6 n and (n/16 + n/16 + n/9)*3?

Comment: Well recursion tree is just a tree with all the recurrence solution combined. So 5/6 n is just n/4+n/4+n/3. (n/16 + n/16 + n/9)*3 should be n/4^2+n/4^2+n/3^2.

Comment: That is just a restatement of *what* is in your tree, and not *why*.  For example: where does the *3 come from?

Comment: I will assume that as there are 2 T(n/4) and 1 T(n/3). Hence 3 recurrence in the recursion tree. Hence *3

Comment: But T(n/3) <> T(n/4), so that isn't 3 occurrences the same thing.

Comment: That's where I am stuck at. Would like to know how to properly derive the recurrence. I know I am wrong.